# How to change the height of a div only with HTML?

Tags: html

This is a normal div

```
<div>First div</div>
```

I do this in order to change the height.

```
<div height="150">
  First div
</div>
```

But nothing happens. I don't see the div taking more than it's usual height.

What might me going on that I'm not seeing?

This is the complete code:

```
    <html>
      <head>
     <title>Probando</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div height="150">
          First div
        </div>
        <div>
          Second Div
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: The height attribute can be used on the following elements: canvas, embed, iframe, img, input, object, video

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `height` attribute, which is deprecated on most HTML elements, you can simply use inline CSS, like in this demo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Probando</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="height: 150px">
    First div
  </div>
  <div>
    Second Div
  </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Better yet, avoid in the inline CSS and use a stylesheet

Comment: True, but I wanted to give him a the most similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should try CSS, HTML element's height and width apply on the table only.

```html
<html>
      <head>
     <title>Probando</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div style="background:#CCC;height:150px">
          First div
        </div>
        <div>
          Second Div
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: It works this way. But why can't I do it only with an HTML property into a div?

Comment: As it's deprecated now, earlier it's used for table, tr, td etc.

Comment: I see, the <div> tag is not included here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_height.asp

Answer (score 1):

You should use inline CSS for this purpose.

```
<div style="height: 150px">
  First div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure html - use `<br>` as many times as div height is enough (no per-pixel precision)

```html
<div>
  First div<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div>
  Second Div
</div>
```